# Race conditions in brownie, how to guarantee this will execute in order?

Tags: transactions, brownie, eth-call

Let's say I have a contract like this:

```
contract Test{
  uint8 test = 0;
  // getter and setter
}
```

and I want to issue it using some python code like:

```
initial = contract.getTest()
contract.setTest(1, {"from": 0x123123123...})
final = contract.getTest()
```

since `getTest` is a call, and `setTest` is a transaction, this should not be safe code right? Or call are dispatched synchronously with transaction and there is no race condition in this code?

Will `getTest` always return 1 if I run the above in order?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question to clarify what you mean by "safe"?

Comment: @PatrickCollins with safe, i mean that there is no race condition in this code... for the example provided, that `final` will always be 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To 100% guarantee that this will execute in order, you can `wait` for a transaction to be mined.

```py
initial = contract.getTest()
set_transaction = contract.setTest(1, {"from": 0x123123123...})
set_transaction.wait(1)
final = contract.getTest()
```

`wait(1)` means we are going to wait 1 block for the transaction to finish.

Comment: since Vitalik said that to be sure that the consensus is reached we need to wait 7/8 blocks, do I need to use `tx.wait(7)`?

Comment: Yes! You got it!

Comment: You know, I'm pretty new to the programming world, but since I started, I loved to help people online (at least for what I can do) and so I'm pretty familiar with StackOverflow... now, in this blog I spent at most two hours, and in those 2 hours, I saw a tons of your answer... at the same time, I'm watching a video on youtube about blockchain, and by pure chance, I saw in the video the  (i suppose it's called) gitlens ext on vscode opening the profile picture of the creator of the video, and he's you, I literally recognized you by pure chance... I mean, thank you so much for all of this!